# mongodb java driver with $match and $gruop

Tags: java, mongodb

when i use this query on mongo shell

```
db.matchgrup.aggregate([{$match:{ "longitude" : {"$gte":73.8172198689148,"$lte":73.8200133489148}, "latitude" :{"$gte":19.98591316489416,"$lte":19.98870664489416} }},{ "$group": {"_id":null, "band_4" : { "$avg" : "$band_4"},"band_8":{"$avg":"$band_8"} } }])
```

it return

```
     { "_id" : null, "band_4" : 1578.8266666666666, "band_8" : 2649.0155555555557 }
```

but when i used mongo java driver for same query

```
              searchQuery1 =new BasicDBObject("longitude", new BasicDBObject("$gte", X.doubleValue()).append("$lte",  px1.doubleValue()));
             criteria.add(searchQuery1);
            searchQuery2=new BasicDBObject("latitude", new BasicDBObject("$gte", py2.doubleValue()).append("$lte",  Y.doubleValue() ));
             criteria.add(searchQuery2); 
              query2=new BasicDBObject("$and",criteria);
              group1 = new BasicDBObject();
             group1.put("_id", null);
             group1.put("band_4", new BasicDBObject("$avg", "$band_4"));
             group1.put("band_8", new BasicDBObject("$avg", "$band_8"));
              output = coll.aggregate(
                     new BasicDBObject("$match",query2),
                     new BasicDBObject("$group",group1));

             for (DBObject doc : output.results()) {
                 band4=(Double)doc.get("band_4");
                 band8=(Double)doc.get("band_8");
             }
```

and it doesn't retuen any value and doesnt goes inside of for loop of doc
can anybody help me out what m doing wrong

Comment: This is the same question being asked by another user, [Using mongo $match with bigdecimal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44643032/using-mongo-match-with-bigdecimal). Are you on the same team?

Comment: Can one of you at least remove your question please. Both will of course have the same solution, so there is little point having both around. You need to break this down. Are you getting anything from the match stage alone? How is it serializing when you log the pipeline statement? For some reason you are adding an explicit `$and` in there, and this would seem a likely source of problems.

Comment: @NeilLunn you mean to say  "query2=new BasicDBObject("$and",criteria);" if i remove that then i will get "errmsg" : "the match filter must be an expression in an object"

Comment: Well yes and I am also saying that for some reason you are mixing a `Criteria` and `BasicDBObject` where you should be using one or the other. The query is really just the first two conditions "appended" to each other to make single object. Just like the query that works in the shell.

Comment: @NeilLunn BasicDBObject is in `BasicDBObject.BasicDBObject(String key, Object value)` how can appen multiple filed i.e is longitude and latitude

Comment: `.append()` It's a method of `BasicDBObject`. i.e `new BasicDBObject("key1", 1).append("key2": 2)` yields `{ "key1" :1, "key2": 2 }`

Comment: @NeilLunn ..yaa now m getting the output ...so problem was  multiple `BasicDBObject`